# Encrypt a directory mounted to docker container

Tags: mount, encryption, security, container

I have a directory on my Ubuntu 18.04 server which is mounted to the root folder of my Apache docker container.

I want a way to get the entire directory encrypted by default. That means whatever data I update or add in that directory via my container gets encrypted automatically in the host directory but is available in a decrypted format inside my container.

My question is: Is this even possible? If yes then how?

I could try to use a password to access my encrypted directory from within container or some other method so that the directory and its updated contents to stay encrypted on the host but are accessible as unencrypted in my container.

Comment: I haven't tried this at all, but you might want to take a look at eCryptfs - just a hint.

Comment: Hi @ArturMeinild I have tried ecryptfs in past but I have been unable to make it work for my requirement with a container mounted directory.

Comment: Fair enough - it was a shot in the dark from my part. ;-) I think what you want to do might actually be quite difficult, unless docker would begin to support native volume encryption, which to my knowledge it does not.

Comment: Maybe take a look at some [docker volume plugins](https://docs.docker.com/engine/extend/legacy_plugins/) - Blockbridge for instance?

Comment: Hmm, this is pretty interesting. Thanks @ArturMeinild for pointing me to this tool. I'll try to explore this and see if it works.